# Datagrip code error highlighting misbehaving, but only in 1 DB

Tags: amazon-redshift, datagrip

I'm using DataGrip to work on a Redshift cluster, which contains a bunch of databases, and error highlighting seems to have gone a bit weird. Let's assume I have `schema_1.table_a` in database `dev` and `schema_2.table_b` in database `test` on the same cluster. If I connect to `dev` and write the query:

`select * from schema_2.table_b` the schema.table reference is highlighted (correctly) as an out of scope error.

However, if I connect to database `test` and write the query:

`select * from schema_1.table_a` there is no error highlighting and DataGrip offers to autocomplete the reference. At runtime, the query unsurprisingly throws an error, since `test` doesn't contain that schema or table.

I find this *especially* weird because it only affects **one** database connection. Extending this example, `test` behaves oddly, but `prod`, `scratch` etc. all behave as expected, highlighting similar out of scope errors.

Is there some database scope setting that I've accidentally changed? Driving me mad trying to debug code as I'm putting it into production.

Deleting the Redshift connection and creating a new one does not affect the behaviour; perhaps this is something to do with postgres / Redshift?

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of your connection settings? Which database is in 'database' field?

Comment: Thanks @moscas! So, there a few DBs in the cluster:
- `legacy` which has the issue described above
- `dev`, `test`, `prod`, `scratch` and a few others, which do not. 

The connection is set up with `scratch` in the db field - everything else is default to the built-in Redshift template (and the same as the other Redshift projects set up & behaving normally). 

It's worth mentioning, that this is also isolated to the specific user. If logged in as root to the same cluster, the issue disappears with `legacy` connections behaving the same as any others.

Answer (score 0):

Currently DataGrip performs broader lookup for object names in console.
It resolves unqualified names both to database/schema you've configured in data source settings and database/schema you've connected to in console.

The reason is simple: we wanted queries to default schema, which are already written, to be highlighted even when you switch schema (imagine all your code becoming yellow at once).
But looks like it don't suite well for PG databases.

We want to make it configurable. Please watch [DBE-6456](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-6456)

Comment: Why don't you use `show search_path` to dynamically retrieve the [schema search path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH)

Comment: As I said, we do use it, but also use default one to keep highlighting after schema switch

Comment: Thanks for your insight @kassak appreciate the help! A few considerations: 

1. The issue doesn't seem to be affected by changing the default database in database source settings or even setting up a new data source for the same user. At the moment (extending the example above), the source settings are set to `scratch`, I'm connected to `legacy` and I get suggestions from both `src` and `dev` databases.
2. As mentioned above, this is only for a single user - in the same cluster using the root user, the suggestions remain restricted to the DB that the console is connected to, as expected.

Comment: @jptk Do you have anything in "SQL Resolution Scopes" in settings?

Comment: @kassak no, nothing in there at all - just default behaviour

Comment: please please create an issue with screenshots of datasource settings and console with broken completion. I'll take a look